# Writing formula into Excel plan via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My question is simple but I am all day long trying to solve it without success.
I want to put this Boolean formula below into an Excel plan using VBA (see codes below).
It will be used like Boolean criteria.
Excel always displays the same error `#Name?` even if the formula is correct.
Note: when I use the key F2 to edit the formula and press ENTER it works in the cell.
Can anybody give me some help?

> ```
> strFórPrefix4 = "=Left(RVplan!A3,4)=Left(""" & rngCél.Value & """,4)"
> rngRótPrefixo4.Offset(1, 0).Formula = strFórPrefix
> ```

Comment: `strFórPrefix` <> `strFórPrefix4`

Comment: Additional to CSerg's absolutely correct comment: Are you really using a `ó` in a varibale name or is that a typo? Same for `rngCél.Value`.

Comment: It is not a typo. I use Fór just because the word Fórmula (in Portuguese).

Comment: Maybe the error occurs because I digit the word 'Esquerda' ('Left' in Portuguese) in code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using special characters for variable names, standard characters.

Try this:

```
strForPrefix4 = "=Left(RVplan!A3,4)=Left(""" & rngCel.Value & """,4)"
rngRotPrefixo4.Offset(1, 0).Formula = strForPrefix4
```

note you should update the variable name of rngCél and rngRótPrefixo4